# How to truncate matrix using NumPy (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

just a quick question, if I have a matrix has n rows and m columns, how can I cut off the 4 sides of the matrix and return a new matrix? (the new matrix would have n-2 rows m-2 columns).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
a[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

Comment: That is fantastically compact! I had only previously seen this done using a tuple of slice(1,-1) objects.

Comment: numpy has some really nice ways of handling indexing and slicing.  I miss the more advanced slicing features when I use Matlab (esp. the broadcasting features).

Answer (score 5):

A more general answer is:

```
a[[slice(1, -1) for _ in a.shape]]
```

Comment: should use a `tuple` to hold the `slice`s for modern Numpy (see [NumPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs))